# Why would it matter if instance storage is SSD or magnetic on on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssd

I'm reading a book on AWS Administration.

> SSDs are behave more like instance storage than EBS volumes, in that
>   **it is not possible to make a snapshot of an SSD**. Data must be loaded
>   on to the SSD each time the instance is used, which can increase the
>   amount of time it takes to bring an instance in to service. However,
>   the massively increased IO speeds of SSD volumes can make up for this
>   shortcoming.

Can somebody explain what's going on here?
You cannot create snapshot of instance storage - that is clear.
But it should not matter if it's SSD or magnetic.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a book of questionable quality, assuming you are not overlooking something, and it does not appear that you are, if you have quoted it accurately.

> Data must be loaded on to the SSD each time the instance is used

Clearly, this is talking about instance storage/ephemeral volumes.  Some instance classes have rotary disks for their instance store, other classes offer SSDs for their instance stores -- but, as written, this is simply incorrect.  There is no such constraint on EBS SSD volumes.  In fact:

> Amazon EBS provides three volume types: General Purpose (SSD), Provisioned IOPS (SSD), and Magnetic. The three volume types differ in performance characteristics and cost, so you can choose the right storage performance and price for the needs of your applications.  **All EBS volume types offer the same durable snapshot capabilities** and are designed for 99.999% availability.
>
> — https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/ (emphasis added)

It is possible that the book is showing its age, since general purpose SSD volumes for EBS relatively recently [became available -- in 2014](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ssd-backed-elastic-block-storage/) but based on the phrasing of the excerpt you've provided, I would be inclined to question the expertise of the author on the topic at hand.

"SSDs are behave more like instance storange than EBS volumes" is a rather nonsensical sentence, implying that there's a third class of volume that's neither ephemeral nor EBS... which there is not.